# OneNote 2013, OCR, imported/printed PDF, reset picture to original size, it highlights wrong place

Tags: pdf, ocr, microsoft-onenote-2013

The title is messy, sorry for that. My point is that if I use the "Send to OneNote" feature, and then right click the print out and choose "restore to original size", the text OCR search will be off-set with the same difference as if the pdf was not made larger. It's consequent like this.

Is this a bug or a feature? I have tried to disable and enable text search, it's still off set.

[image: screenshot]

After more testing it seems to only apply to printouts, and not actual pictures inserted with <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>, but only to pdf/word/prints via the send to onenote feature.

Comment: Can you please add a screen-shot to illustrate?

Comment: I added a link to an imgur picture. It shows how the highlight misses the area after I use "restore to default size".

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use for this is - After resizing the image, rightclick the image, choose 'make text in image searchable' then change the language. Click back on the image then go back into that option and change it back to your language. I changed it to French and then back to English, then the searches highlight the correct position for the text in the image again.